# How to bind a parameter to Cart::create in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to store current user's `user_id` in database in Laravel:

```
public function AddToCart(Request $request)
{
 Cart::create([
 'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id, 
 'product_id'=>$request->AddToCart
 ]);

return redirect('#');
}
```

Here `user_id` is an attribute and `$userId` is the user's id which I want to store in the database. But I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple with laravel. you can do it like this; also we need to check if the user it is actually authenticate d

```
if (Auth::user()) {
  Cart::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 
    'product_id' => $request->AddToCart
  ]);
}
```

don't forget to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; at the top of your class.

For the error that you are getting, one possible solution could be to create a new migration: `php artisan make:migration modify_user_id_in_carts_tabel --table=carts` and add the following: note that you may need to run `composer require doctrine/dbal` if you dont have it.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
```

Comment: now getting error i.e SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: have you use the facade at the top.

Comment: done
thank u to all :)